# Checking if estimator $\hat{\theta}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2}$ is unbiased

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Let $P_\theta(X=x) = \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^2(1-\theta)^{1-x^2}$ for $x=-1,0,1$

Let $\hat{\theta}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2}$ be an estimator of $\theta$. Is it unbiased?

So the formula that is needed to check if it is biased or not:
$$Bias\left(\hat{\theta}\right) = E\left(\hat{\theta}\right) - \theta = 0$$

But I don't really know how to get the expected value here.

$$E\left(\hat{\theta}\right) = E\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2}\right) = \frac{1}{n}E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2}\right)$$

And I am somehow lost now. What should be my next steps? How to deal with the summation?

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (or other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Your probability distribution isn't normalized. The probabilities for $X=±1$ are $\left(\frac\theta2\right)^2$, the probability for $X=0$ is $1-\theta$ times that, so the sum is $(3-\theta)\left(\frac\theta2\right)^2\ne1$.

Comment: @joriki Well, was thinking about something like that too. But didn't really get into it. Will try it out now. But hmm... how did $3$ appear there? I mean $3-\theta$

Comment: It comes from $\sum_{x=-1,0,1} P_{\theta}(X=x) = \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right)^2 (3 - \theta)$.